# ElasticSearch sorting by multiple scripts

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying to use multiple scripts to sort results in Elastic 6.7

Unfortunately, I didn't find a way trying a lot of combinations.

**I can't use only one script to do everything, because filters and sortings are dynamic.**

This is my query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": []
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": [
      {
        "type": "number",
        "order": "desc",
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "doc['status.keyword'].value == 'active' ? 1 : 0;"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "number",
        "order": "desc",
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "(doc['s_price'].value/doc['currency.usd_c'].value*params.cvs)",
          "params": {
            "cvs": 42.71
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
POST /_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.active += ctx._source['status.keyword'].value == 'active' ? 1 : 0;",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}

GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [],
                  "filter": []
                }
              },
            "script_score" : {
                "script": {
                  "source": "(doc['s_price'].value/doc['currency.usd_c'].value*params.cvs)",
                  "params": {
                    "cvs": 42.71
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [{
        "active": "desc"
    },
    {
        "score": "desc"
    }]
}
```

Add a field `active` for one of the queries using bulk update. And use a `function_score` query to calculate the other value. Sort first by `active` and then by `score`

Answer (score 1):

With [runtime fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime.html) sorting with more than one script got a lot easier. If you're using ES 7.11 or later just define one runtime field per script and use the fields to sort the data:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [],
            "filter": []
        }
    },
    "runtime_mappings": {
        "active": {
            "type": "long",
            "script": {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "emit(doc['status.keyword'].value == 'active' ? 1 : 0);"
            }
        },
        "price": {
            "type": "long",
            "script": {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "emit(doc['s_price'].value/doc['currency.usd_c'].value*params.cvs)",
                "params": {
                    "cvs": 42.71
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "active": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "price": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note, the scripts in runtime fields cannot use `return` for emitting values but you need to use the `emit` function.